# Analysis Services - Actions

Tags: ssas

I haven't found a good use for Analysis Services actions yet (apart from the obvious hyperlink action).

What do you use the other ones for (if anything)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played with the reporting action a bit, but the most used action, I would say, is the Drillthrough action.  This lets your users see your underlying cube values from a tool like Excel with just a right-click.  The next most used action would probably be the Rowset action.  I actually used the Rowset action to define a custom drillthrough-type action for times when I needed to drill through to rows other than the ones which strictly make up the currently selected entry.

Answer (score 1):

Right click 'Additonal Actions' in excel 2010.. I can wire up Reporting Services reports. It's easier than doing the URL actions.  This is an AWESOME feature!!